# C++ Program To Find Smallest and Largest Number In Array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Beginner in C++ here and learning arrays. The program below is supposed to return the smallest and largest number in an array using two separate functions. One for the largest and one for the smallest number. However, it is returning 0 all the time for function lastLowestIndex and I am unsure what I may be doing wrong.

Could someone ever so kindly advice and show me what is incorrect in that function and what can be done to correct it so that it returns the correct value? I am obviously not seeing and/or understanding what is incorrect.

Thank you so very much for your help and time in advance!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int lastLargestIndex(int [], int);
int lastLowestIndex(int [], int );

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int N = 15;
   int arr[N] = {5,198,76,9,4,2,15,8,21,34,99,3,6,13,61};
   int location;
   //int location2;

   location = lastLargestIndex( arr, N );

   cout << "The last largest number is:" << location << endl;

  location = lastLowestIndex(arr, N);

  cout << "The last smallest number is:" << location << endl;


  // std::system ("pause");

   return 0;
}

int lastLargestIndex( int arr[], int size )
{
   int highNum = 0;

   for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
   {
      if ( arr[i]  > highNum )
      {
         highNum = arr[i];
      }
   }

   return highNum;
}

int lastLowestIndex(int arr[], int size)
{

    int smallest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < smallest)
        {

            smallest = arr[i];

        }

    }

    //cout << smallest << '\n';

    return smallest;


}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: If you need to do this in "real" code, you probably want to use `std::minmax_element`, which (as you can probably guess from the name) is defined to do *precisely* what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, it is returning 0 all the time for function lastLowestIndex and I am unsure what I may be doing wrong.

You got a logic error when you initialised `smallest` to `0` in function `lastLowestIndex()` - that way `if (arr[i] < smallest)` condition is not evaluated to `true` if all input is positive. Instead, you should initialise it to the first member of array `arr`. The function should look like this:

```
int lastLowestIndex(int arr[], int size)
{

    int smallest = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`lastLowestIndex()` initialises `smallest` to be `0`, and then compares all elements of the array (which are positive, in your example) with it.   All positive values are greater than zero, so smallest will remain zero.

Note that your logic is also not general for finding the maximum.  Consider what the code will do if all elements of the array are negative.

You would be better off adopting a logic that does not make any assumptions about the array, other than its size and that it contains integral values.   For example;

```
int lastLargestIndex( int arr[], int size )
{
    int highNum = arr[0];

    for( int i = 1; i < size; i++ )
    {
        if ( arr[i]  > highNum )
        {
            highNum = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return highNum;
}
```

This doesn't exhibit the problems yours does, since it initialises `highNum` with the first element of the array, and iterates over the rest (if any).   This does assume size is positive.

Your functions are also named in a misleading manner, since they (attempt to) return the maximum (or minimum) value in the array, but their name suggests they will return the index of that value.   I'll leave resolving that little issue as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct working code!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int lastLargestIndex(int [], int);
int lastLowestIndex(int [], int );

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int N = 15;
   int arr[N] = {5,198,76,9,4,2,15,8,21,34,99,3,6,13,61};
   int location;

   location = lastLargestIndex( arr, N );
   cout << "The last largest number is:" << location << endl;
   location = lastLowestIndex(arr, N);
   cout << "The last smallest number is:" << location << endl;
   // std::system ("pause");
   return 0;
 }

int lastLargestIndex( int arr[], const int size )
{
   int highNum = -100001;
   for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
   {
      if ( arr[i]  > highNum )
      {
         highNum = arr[i];
      }
   }
   return highNum;
}

int lastLowestIndex(int arr[], const int size)
{
    int smallest = 100001;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    //cout << smallest << '\n';
   return smallest;
}
```

Modifications done:

1. Replaced argument in function from `int size` to `const int size`, since `N` is declared as `const int` in `main` function
2. Replaced `highNum` with `-100001`
3. Replaced `smallest` with `100001`

Comment: What do you expect to happen on an implementation with a 32-bit `int`, and if any of the values in the array are either less than `-100001` or greater than `100001`?

Comment: @Peter, We can use INT_MIN and INT_MAX, so as to have proper limits. And it will vary depending on the system as stated [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).